# Add timestamp to signed AppX bundle

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, certificate, code-signing

Our Windows Store app is signed by Visual Studio with our custom code signing certificate to allow sideloading of the resulting AppX bundle.

[image: Selected certificate in Visual Studio]

The AppX bundle generated by Visual Studio (during the `_CreateBundle` build step I guess) will add no trusted timestamp to the digital signature. This prevents the bundle from being installed after the certficate has expired.

[image]

Is there a way to adjust or configure the `_CreateBundle` build task to add a timestamp during the packaging and singing process? I looked into SignTool (which we use for code signing MSI packages), but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835(v=vs.85).aspx) yields

> You can't use the SignTool time stamp operation on a signed app package; the operation isn't supported.

.. and my package is already signed by Visual Studio within the `_CreateBundle` step as it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clearify the documentation: One cannot add a timestamp to an already signed package, but `SignTool` can re-sign the package and include a timestamp. So I added a post-build event to re-sign the bundle generated by Visual Studio:

```
if $(SolutionName) == Installer (
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /fd SHA256 /a /f "$(ProjectDir)..\..\Build\CodeSigning.pfx" /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com "$(TargetDir)AppPackages\my_app\my_app.appxbundle"
)
```

Comment: FYI- This doesn't sign anything that's inside of the package, though, such as the `Codeintegrity.cat` file.  So if the signature of anything within the bundle is validated, it will fail once the signing certificate has expired.

Comment: There appears to be a good tutorial on how to force the use of a timestamp server when building an AppX package here: https://blog.jayway.com/2017/01/16/time-stamping-appx-packages/