# Extend the existing Windows app expired certificate

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

One of our windows 8.1 app got its certificate expired and we are not able to generate new builds.Is there a way to extend the same certificate for upcoming builds.

Right now i tried with post-build event and couldn't achieve the same.

```
if $(SolutionName) == Installer ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /fd SHA256 /a /f "$(ProjectDir)..\..\Build\CodeSigning.pfx" /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com "$(TargetDir)AppPackages\my_app\my_app.appxbundle")
```

Refernce [Add timestamp to signed AppX bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798449/add-timestamp-to-signed-appx-bundle)

In this post build which certificate to be mapped. Expired certificate or a new certificate

Note: There is an option to add new certificate but it changes the app **"Package family name"**. I don'n need to change my package family name since the data in old package is needed.

Comment: Do you have a new cert which is issued to the same Publisher (usually your company’s name)? The the Publisher name of the cert stays the same, the package family name will not get changed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Let me check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Package Family Name (PFN)` consists of two parts,

The first is the Package name you choose.

The second is a hash of the Publisher name, which is the Publisher field of the signing certificate.

So when renewing the signing certificate, make sure the new cert's Publisher stays the same, then the Package Family Name won't change.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of hash it is?

Comment: @Prabhakaran I don’t know. Some kind of message digest. I read it somewhere which did not state the hash algorithm either.